# Retrieve primary key value of table when search for values in other column

Tags: sql, string, primary-key

I am using this snippet to find a specific string in any table of the database!

```
DECLARE @searchstring  NVARCHAR(255)
SET @searchstring = '%foo%'

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)

SELECT @sql = STUFF((
    SELECT ' UNION ALL SELECT ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' ' +
    ' FROM ' + TABLE_NAME + 
    ' WHERE ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' LIKE ''' + @searchstring + ''''
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE DATA_TYPE in ('nvarchar', 'varchar', 'char','nchar')
    FOR XML PATH('')
) ,1, 11, '')


exec (@sql)
```

But I would like to get the Primary Key Value of these entries!

To get the primary key of a specific table I use

```
SELECT ccu.COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc 
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE ccu ON tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = ccu.Constraint_name 
    WHERE tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'Primary Key' 
    AND tc.TABLE_NAME = 'tbl_table'
```

but I can't combine both?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some tables may have more than one column in the primary key and other may have no primary key. That makes this task a bit harder and the resulting column needs to be a list of primary key values in one column.

```
SELECT @sql = STUFF((
    SELECT ' UNION ALL SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(C.COLUMN_NAME) + ', ' +
               ISNULL(STUFF((SELECT '+'', ''+CAST('+QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)+' AS VARCHAR(MAX))'
                             FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS TC
                               INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE AS CU
                                 ON TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CU.CONSTRAINT_NAME AND
                                    TC.TABLE_NAME = CU.TABLE_NAME
                             WHERE CU.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME AND
                                   TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
                             FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 6, ''), '''''')+' AS PrimaryKeys'+
    ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(C.TABLE_NAME) + 
    ' WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(C.COLUMN_NAME) + ' LIKE ''' + @searchstring + ''''
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS C
    WHERE C.DATA_TYPE in ('nvarchar', 'varchar', 'char','nchar')
    ORDER BY C.TABLE_NAME
    FOR XML PATH('')
) ,1, 11, '')
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c4036/5)

Using the tables in the fiddle the generated query will look like this.

```
SELECT [Col], 
       CAST([ID] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS PrimaryKeys 
FROM [T1] 
WHERE [Col] LIKE '%foo%' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT [Col], 
       CAST([Col] AS VARCHAR(MAX))+', '+CAST([ID] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS PrimaryKeys 
FROM [T2] 
WHERE [Col] LIKE '%foo%' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT [Col], 
       '' AS PrimaryKeys 
FROM [T3] 
WHERE [Col] LIKE '%foo%'
```